# MySQL query works in Workbench but hibernate throws MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a query that it is bringing me 2 results. It works properly when I use it on MySQL Workbench, but when I use it on my hibernate mapping as a formula, I'm getting this error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [FacesServlet] in context with
>   path [/glic_web_admin] threw exception
>   [javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet] with root cause
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'shipmentre0_.SEPARATOR ', ') FROM glic_shipment s  LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   glic_shipment' at line 1

Here is my SQL query in hibernate mapping:

```
<property name="supplier" type="java.lang.String"
            formula="(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pnSon.supplier SEPARATOR ', ')
     FROM glic_shipment s 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN glic_shipment sSon ON sSon.id_shipment_parent = s.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN glic_rel_purchase_shipment_common_data pscdSon ON pscdSon.id = sSon.id_common_data
     LEFT OUTER JOIN glic_purchase_notice pnSon ON pnSon.id = pscdSon.id_purchase_notice)" />
```

The expected output of this query is a String which have the results concatenated. I know it's a syntax problem but I didn't find how to solve this.

**EDIT:**
This is the query that hibernate is executing:

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pnSon.supplier shipmentre0_.SEPARATOR ', ') FROM glic_shipment s  LEFT OUTER JOIN glic_shipment sSon ON sSon.id_shipment_parent = s.id LEFT OUTER JOIN glic_rel_purchase_shipment_common_data pscdSon ON pscdSon.id = sSon.id_common_data LEFT OUTER JOIN glic_purchase_notice pnSon ON pnSon.id = pscdSon.id_purchase_notice) as formula27_0_
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: add <property name="show_sql">true</property> in hbm config and post the query that is outputed

Comment: @MaciejKowalski check the edit, thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not to write `SEPARATOR ', '` try as follows:

```
<property name="supplier" type="java.lang.String"
            formula="(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pnSon.supplier, ' ')
     FROM glic_shipment s 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN glic_shipment sSon ON sSon.id_shipment_parent = s.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN glic_rel_purchase_shipment_common_data pscdSon ON pscdSon.id = sSon.id_common_data
     LEFT OUTER JOIN glic_purchase_notice pnSon ON pnSon.id = pscdSon.id_purchase_notice)" />
```